# -Dmapred.job.name does not work with s3-dist-cp command

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, distcp, s3distcp

I'd like to copy some files from emr-hdfs to s3 bucket using s3-dist-cp, I've tried this cmd from "EMR Master Node":

```
s3-dist-cp -Dmapred.job.name=my_copy_job --src hdfs:///user/hadoop/abc s3://my_bucket/my_key/
```

this command executes fine but when I check the job name in yarn resource manager UI, it displays like this:
`S3DistCp hdfs:///user/hadoop/abc **->** s3://my_bucket/my_key/`

whereas, the expected job name should have been `my_copy_job`

Appreciate for any help,!

**Note:**
when I run hadoop distcp with this option `-Dmapred.job.name=my_copy_job`, it displays job name correctly in yarn RM UI, but the job eventually fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3-dist-cp` does not support `-D` style properties set during the runtime as `hadoop distcp` does. S3 Distcp accepts only a finite set of options as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html#UsingEMR_s3distcp.options). In addition to these options defined by `S3DistCp`, it accepts the [Tool Interface's](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) generic options.

But `JobName` is not one of them. `JobName` is [hardcoded](https://github.com/libin/s3distcp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/external/elasticmapreduce/s3distcp/S3DistCp.java#L320) in the S3DistCp code and cannot be overriden.

Comment: Thanks,! so, is this a limitation for s3-dist-cp, that it does not allow to customize the name of job? our requirement is to show appropriate job in Yarn Resource Managaer UI

Comment: Yes, jobname cannot be modified. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, however, I've done this by using "hadoop distcp" just to fulfill the client's requirement for now, though this way I am losing the optimization that s3-dist-cp offers over "hadoop-distcp"

Comment: How can the Tools interface be used to change some settings (like s3DistCp.copyfiles.reducer.tempDir)? Configuring some file? Using some magic parameter? (I have tested with -Ds3DistCp.copyfiles.reducer.tempDir=xxx but it complains about unregnized options)

Comment: Could you please provide the complete command that you tried